# ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer::NoSerializerError in active_model_serializer 0.10.0.rc5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, grape-api

I'm using `active_model_serializer 0.10.0.rc5` and `grape gem` for the api.

I've a post endpoint like this :

```
class V1::Endpoints::Posts < Grape::API
  resource :posts do
    desc 'Returns a list of posts.'
    # serializing array
    get '', each_serializer: V1::Serializers::PostSerializer  do
      @posts = Post.all
      present @posts
    end
  end
end
```

My serializer looks something like this :

```
class V1::Serializers::PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :slug
end
```

Now when I try to access the post endpoint I get the following error :

```
ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer::NoSerializerError - No serializer found for resource:
```

The issue which I figured out while debugging the issue lies in the `CollectionSerializer#initialize` of this gem. I suppose that the `serializer_class` variable is coming out to be nil.

I've tried almost all the links which seemed relevant for this problem. But none worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

try to use serializer instead of each_serializer:

```
get '', serializer: V1::Serializers::PostSerializer  do
```

Instead of:

```
get '', each_serializer: V1::Serializers::PostSerializer  do
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended using a DRYed version of `render json: @object, serializer: Namespaced::ObjectSerializer`.

Since I have found little information on this matter, I've posted this approach here: [Correct way to implement API versioning with active_model_serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000787/correct-way-to-implement-api-versioning-with-active-model-serializers)

I hope it helps!