# Namespacing API with Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to namespacing API for a Rails based application.

I use `Active Model Serializer` but now I need to versioning my API.

How?

I have yet subdomain constraints. For API, I wish to have...

`api.domain.com/v1/users/`

with (for example) `:id` and `:name` for `User`

`api.domain.com/v2/users/`

with (for example) `:id` `:name` `:ranking` for `User`

So, how should I create different `Serializer`, one for each namespace?

And... Must I create different `Serializer` in different controllers or different files? How exactly?

Thanks to all.

**UPDATE**

Some code:

`routes.rb`

```
constraints subdomain: 'api', default: {format: 'json'} do   #api.domain.com

#API V1
namespace :v1 do 
#resources for v1
end

#API V1
namespace :v2 do 
#resources for v2
end
```

I have in `controllers/v1/resource_controller.rb` with `module V1` and `render json: @list` that renders **ALL** information of the resource.

So, Rails is not calling my serializer placed in `serializers/v1/resource_serializer.rb`

**EDIT:** Namespaces are valid!

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000787/correct-way-to-implement-api-versioning-with-active-model-serializers/38001311#38001311

Comment: @MirzaMemic thank you. I've read but now Serializer are not used by Rails. Please check update on question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [@Mirza Memic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6427566/mirza-memic) is better to specify also the serializer when call `render json:`

with `each_serializer: TopModule::SubModule::CustomSerializer`

otherwise we could get error (`model_name` or `read_attribute_for_serialization`) if is a collection (simply `serializer:` instead of `each_serializer:` **ONLY if is a SINGLE object**)

Of course controller must be "sub-foldered" for each module name, as suggested [@Júlio Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787989/j%c3%balio-campos).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 controllers, 2 serializers and define your routes.

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :foo
  end

  namespace :v2 do
    resources :foo
  end
end
```

And your controllers:

```
class Api::V1::FooController < ApplicationController
#...
end
```

And

```
class Api::V2::FooController < ApplicationController
#...
end
```

Your serializers also need to have /v1 and /v2 in name.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm near a solution. Could you be more clear? I need a subfolder in serializer? Or only different class with V1 and V2 in name with one .rb files and different classes?

Comment: Only different files.