# Can't access V1::JobSerializer inside of V1::JobsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am using `ActiveModelSerializers` gem with my Rails API project.

I created a `JobsController` inside of `app/controllers/v1/jobs_controller.rb` because of API versioning.

I also created a `JobSerializer` inside of `app/serializers/v1/job_serializer.rb` also because of API versioning.

When I try to access `V1::JobSerializer` inside of the controller like this:

```rb
  def today_jobs 
    todays_jobs = Job.where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page] ? params[:page].to_i : 1).per(10)

    render json: {objects: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(todays_jobs, each_serializer: V1::JobSerializer), meta: pagination_meta(todays_jobs)}
  end
```

Don't mind the pagination, this part is important:

```rb
objects: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(todays_jobs, each_serializer: V1::JobSerializer)
```

When I try to return this it says `uncaught throw :no_serializer` because I think it doesn't know what `V1::JobSerializer` is.

Just to make sure:
`jobs_controller.rb` is defined like this:

```rb
class V1::JobsController < ApplicationController
end
```

and `job_serializer.rb` is defined like this:

```rb
class V1::JobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
end
```

What should I do to be able to access `V1::JobSerializer` inside of my jobs controller?

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053962/activemodelserializercollectionserializernoserializererror-in-active-model

Comment: Try supplying the namespace option instead, https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/rendering.md#namespace

Comment: Surprisingly it worked by only removing `V1::` from the class naming in `job_serializer.rb` and adding `module V1`. Any idea why that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope resolution operator `::` should never be used when declaring nested classes / modules. Always use explicit nesting:

```
# Bad:
class V1::JobsController < ApplicationController
  puts JobSerializer.inspect # missing constant error
end

class V1::JobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
end
```

```
# Good:
module V1
  class JobsController < ApplicationController
    puts JobSerializer.inspect # resolves to V1::JobSerializer 
  end
end

module V1
  class JobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  end
end
```

Why? Because when you use the scope resolution operator the module nesting is resolved to the place of definition. And this can lead to extremely suprising constant lookup:

```
A = "I'm in the main scope"

module B
  A = "I'm in B"
  D = "Hello"
end

class B::C 
  puts A # outputs "I'm in the main scope"
  puts D # Missing constant error
end
```

When you use explicit nesting you actually reopen the module/class and set the correct module nesting so that constants are resolved in the same module:

```
module B
  class C
    puts A # outputs "I'm in B"
    puts D # outputs "Hello"
  end
end
```

Comment: That's the exact explanation I was looking for. Perfect, thanks